# embedding current user id in a form Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I am trying to validate a form in Symfony 2.3. I need to get the current User id and submit in my database.

My controller :

```
   public function giftcardAction(Request $request)
    {
        $giftcard = new Giftcard();
        $giftcard->setDate(new \DateTime());
        $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        $userId = $user->getId();

        var_dump($userId);
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($giftcard)
            ->add('amount', 'integer')
            ->add('onBehalfOf')
            ->add('towards')
            ->add('message', 'text')
//            ->add($userId)
            ->add('submit', 'submit')
            ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($giftcard);
            $em->flush();

        }else{
            throw new NotFoundHttpException("Page not found");
           }
        }
            return $this->render('FrontBundle:Forms:giftcard.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

## My FormType

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class GiftCardType extends AbstractType
{
    private $userId;

    public function __construct(array $userId)
    {
        $this->userId = $userId;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('date')
            ->add('onBehalfOf')
            ->add('towards')
            ->add('message')
//            ->add('UserId')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Front\Bundle\Entity\GiftCard',
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'front_bundle_giftcard';
    }
}
```

At the moment i can get the user id in var_dump in the controller. But how I can pass the variable in the form. Has anyone may help me. Thank you.

Comment: If you're looking to associate a User with the Gift Card, I'd create a one to one Unidirectional relationship for that entity.  Then inside your `if($form-isValid())` you'll do something like `$giftcard->setUser($user)` before persisting to the database.  Doctrine or whatever ORM you use will automatically get the User Id and put it into the database for you.  This also helps in the future when you retrieve that gift card, you won't have to do extra steps changing that id back into a User, it'll just happen automatically when you do `$giftcard->getUser()`

Comment: Why array UserId if it's a single ID?